# How to build and package only the relevant dependencies using nx?

Tags: typescript, npm, dependency-management, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a project using `nx` that has many packages in it. My problem is that I only have a single `package.json` file so if I want to build only one package I still have to build the root project using `npm install`.

This is a problem because during the CI/CD step I have to build the whole project which is taking too long, and it also generates a single `node_modules` folder that becomes huge (3GB) which also makes my bundle size prohibitively big.

How can I build individual packages in a way that the `node_modules` folder will only contain the dependencies that my package needs instead of having all the dependencies of all packages?

If that's not possible how can I compile a single executable `main.js` file that bundles all those dependencies?

*Edit: I tried splitting the `package.json` file for all the packages, but whenever I build an individual package I still get all the dependencies loaded into the `node_modules` folder in the root. Is it possible to have a `node_modules` folder for each individual package?*

Comment: Note: if you interested in space savings for `node_modules`, you may be interested in [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/)

Comment: I don't want to add yet another tool to my build process. There must be a solution within `nx` for this problem.

Comment: Maybe with `affected` not an nx user. But you might be able to do `nx affected --target="install"`

Comment: I've solved the problem in another way. Not pretty, but it works at least.

Comment: @AdamArold Could you share Your solution?

Comment: @AdamArold please share your solution, we are eager to know.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I've added an answer!

Comment: @ShlomiBazel 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution that is not ideal, but it works at least. What the `generatePackageJson` does is that it creates a `package.json` file in the build folder that can be used to run the build **again** to produce a `node_modules` folder that only contains the dependencies of the specific target. So in my case what I did is to add `"generatePackageJson": true` to my `build` target in my backend package:

```json
{
  "sourceRoot": "apps/backend/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      // ...
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/backend",
        "main": "apps/backend/src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/backend/tsconfig.app.json",
        "generatePackageJson": true, // 
        "assets": [
          "apps/backend/src/assets"
        ]
      }
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I run `nx build backend` I'll have something in `dist/apps/backend` that can be used as a standalone project. Unfortunately `npm` checks the parent folders for `package.json` files and messes up everything so I ended up writing a build script that cleans up the project and enables easy deployment. (This works with Heroku but it is easy to adapt to other PaaS / IaaS solutions. I'm gonna paste it here verbatim:

> Note that this script runs from the root folder, so our backend dist folder is at `dist/apps/backend` relative to where this script runs. (I keep the scripts in the `script` folder. You are also **not supposed to run this locally** as it deletes stuff form the project. Only run this in a CI/CD environment.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

print_usage() {
    echo " $1"
    echo "Help below "
    echo ""
    echo "Builds the specified project for Heroku."
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: ./heroku-build <nx-project-name>"
    echo ""
    echo "__Note that__ this script is intended to be used from CI/CD, you probably won't need it during development."
    exit 1
}

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    print_usage "Project name is missing!"
fi

# Heroku build is a little bit different because they have a slug size (deployment size) limit of 500MB.
# If you build the project (not just the package) you'll end up with a `node_modules` folder that's ridiculously big (3GB)
# but it can't be pruned properly. If you think you can prune it without this hacky solution go ahead, but it is unlikely
# that you'll be able to figure it out. **If** you try it please increment the counter below:
# 
# total_hours_wasted_trying_to_prune_node_modules=13
# 
# So how this works is that Heroku will run `npm install --prod` that will delete devDependencies too, so
#  DON'T MOVE nx and @nrwl packages to devDependencies! 
# After the project is built you'll have the horrendous `node_modules` folder, but it's not a big deal as we'll delete it.

# Build the project with nx
nx build $1 --prod

# This step is necessary because npm will look for `package.json` files in the parent folder and it will use the `node_modules`
# folder from the parent folder. We don't want that, we want to have only the necessary packages (backend) in the `node_modules` folder.
mv package.json package.json.bak
mv package-lock.json package-lock.json.bak

# We get rid of all the unnecessary packages.
rm -Rf node_modules

# We install the necessary packages.
# In the `nx build` step nx generates a `package.json` that only contains the dependencies of the backend project
# so this will *only* () download 500MB from npm.
npm install dist/apps/backend

# More reading on this problem:
#
# - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73373307/how-to-build-and-package-only-the-relevant-dependencies-using-nx?noredirect=1#comment129738870_73373307
# - https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1518
# - https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1706#issuecomment-579248915
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this very helpful, especially the links. I found no need to nuke the parent node_modules or .json files.  A simple `npm install` before packaging it was all that was needed with node 16. (`npm ci` failed on my project because there was some imperfection in the lock file created by nx)